# Unsung Hero badge: how does it work exactly?

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer, zero-score-badges

I was just checking [How Unsung am I?](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i) and I discovered that I currently have *6 unscored answers* and *22.2% percent unscored.*

How does the *unscored answers* count work?

1. It counts all accepted answers I have at the present moment with 0 upvotes;
2. It counts all answers that had no votes at the time they were accepted;

Let me give you an example: if the 1st option was right, that means that if one of my 6  0-scored accepted answers gets an **upvote right now**, it would decrease the Unsung count and make me work a little harder to get the badge.

Which one is it?

Comment: Shameless plug for my proposal to tweak the badge definition to not count OP upvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62473

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the present moment. Otherwise it'd matter whether — in one common case — the OP accepted then upvoted, or upvoted then accepted. Think of it this way: if the answer reaches positive score, it's not really unsung anymore.

Comment: it only counts accepted answers or only counts answers not accepted?

Comment: @aF. Only accepted answers count.