# Do negative score/accepted answers count towards tenacious/unsung hero?

Tags: discussion, zero-score-badges

My guess is no.  And I think my opinion (if that is correct) is that is probably the way it should be.  But I'm interested in the opinion of others once someone posts the official answer.

Also, I'm assuming "zero score" is in the [literal sense of the word score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97927/does-score-refer-to-rep-points-or-votes-i-e-generalist-badge)

(i.e. one negative and one positive vote is still a zero score).

Comment: Answers with a zero score are answers where the number of up-votes is equal to the number of down-votes, which can both be zero.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We check the *net* score, so a post with 1 upvote and 1 downvote **would** qualify as a "zero score" answer.  A negatively downvoted post with a net negative would *not* qualify.

Comment: It makes sense that this is how "zero score" is defined, but to me +1/-1 isn't the same as 0 in the context of the badge. Am I just being silly/is there a reason why it's done this way?

Comment: @Tim - well, the alternative would be a bit (well, *very* actually) nasty in terms of performance, but other than that...I don't know of a strong reason one way or the other really.

Comment: @NickCraver, I know about a really strong reason for not accounting these +1/-1, please [read here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117224/unsung-hero-only-unscored-answers-should-count-instead-of-zero-scored). Is looking for unscored post so much performance demanding? I'd imagine just simple `posts left join Votes where Votes.Id is NULL` :-)

Comment: @Tomas - It's not that simple, no.  Other things are stored on the Posts2Votes table like Favorites, Bounties, Spam/Offensive flags, etc....so checking that's there's "just nothing" on one side of the join is not doable no - it'd require a different/distinct index than exists now to not time out, for a badge that works as-designed at the moment.  Remember we're on SSDs and small ones at the moment, we don't create large indexes lightly - and almost never for a single (relatively) rarely used query.

Answer (score 3):

Answers with a zero score are answers where the number of up-votes is equal to the number of down-votes, which can both be zero.

The answers that are considered for the badge must be at least ten days old, not self-accepted, and not wiki.