# Is a question considered Zero Score Accepted if it has 1 upvote and 1 downvote?

Tags: support, badges, score, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do negative score/accepted answers count towards tenacious/unsung hero?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97937/do-negative-score-accepted-answers-count-towards-tenacious-unsung-hero)

Let's say someone asks a question, I answer it, they accept my answer and vote me up. Someone else votes me down. My score is now 0. Is it considered a Zero Score Accepted answer? (As pr. Tenacious & Unsung Hero badges.)

Comment: I see something similar has been asked before. Flagging this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is the [net score that matters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97940/176080).