# Unsung hero badge: from 11 answers or 10?

Tags: discussion, badges

In the [explanation of Unsung Hero badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) you can read:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

What does `more than 10` mean? "11 or more" or "10 or more"?

**Edit**: Of course I do know what is the mathematical deffinition of this concept, but it looks strange for a limit to be supposedly based on number 11 instead of 10.

**Regarding the bounty**: I was expecting an *official* answer and could not get it. Hence, the bounty will be unawarded.

Comment: What does "more than 10 mean"? Hmmm.... Exactly 7.

Comment: Fair enough question I guess, at least one post suggests it's 10 or more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123521/159834

Comment: Do we still not know? I got 10/38 and 10 days old on the maths forum, no badge. How often does the system check who needs to be awarded a badge?

Comment: I never got an authoritative answer, @Lost1 The system checks it every day, I think.

Comment: @fedorqui the definitive answer is 11, I am a counterexample to 10. :) I deliberately waited 11 days without answering any more questions and no answers were accepted during this time. still no badge.

Comment: @Lost1 so by Reductio ad absurdum we found out that it is 11 :) Once you get the Unsung Hero badge with 11 answers, post as an answer and I will accept so everyone can know!

Comment: @fedorqui i got another 2 zero-scored. now another 11 days of waiting... but my answers normally get no votes, so i just keep on posting them anyway.

Comment: @Lost1 now I see you finally got the Unsung Hero badge. How long did it take? Was it 10 or 11 questions?

Comment: @fedorqui 11 :)

Comment: Nice so now that we have a "practical example" of it being 11 and not 10, you can post an answer if you want. I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is 11. I stopped posting at 10 for more than 10 days and I got nothing. Only got the badge when I got more than 11 answers.

Answer (score 9):

It means 10 or more. [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2833%20isaccepted:yes%20score:0) of a user who has the "Unsung hero" badge and has exactly 10 zero score answers.

As @Caleb points out, this user might have had 11 answers and one of them get upvoted after earning the badge. However, I have checked it with [this query on SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103595/unsung-heroes-with-exactly-10-zero-score-accepted-answers): It retrieves all the users with exactly 10 zero score answers created before earning the badge, so it is possible to be qualified with this number of answers.

There are also some posts on where it is said concretely "at least 10 answers", like this [@Martijn Pieters's accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166608/total-accepted-answers-for-unsung-hero#166622), or this [@NullUserException's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/tweak-the-definition-of-unsung-hero-and-tenacious-badges#comment-154035)

> So, to put it differently, the query for the badge looks up all accepted answers that are
> 10 days old, and are not self-accepted, deleted or community wiki, then checks that at
> least 10 of those are at 0 points and if that makes for more than 25% of the qualifying
> accepted answers.

Comment: I'm not sure that's conclusive evidence -- one or more of their zero-score answers could have been voted up between the time they got the badge and now, leaving only 10 remaining. Notice that that user also has 51 answers total, so they'd fail the 25% of total test.

Comment: @Caleb Users keep this badge even when they don't qualify anymore, so he earned it in a moment where he had <=40 accepted answers. Just for curiosity, I've looked at his zero score answers and all are +0/-0, so definitely is 10 or more.

Comment: My point is that the user may have had 11 or more accepted answers with zero score, and one or more were upvoted after the badge was awarded. Since, as you say, users keep the badge even if they lose the qualification, the fact that they have 10 now doesn't mean that only 10 are required for the badge.

Comment: @Caleb I get your point; however, I've added the condition `b.Date > a.CreationDate` and there are still results. It means this answers may have changed their score later, but when the badge was earned they had a score of 0 without votes (otherwise it'd be impossible to earn the badge).

Comment: Isn't a +1/-1 answer still 0 score? I always assumed that such answers can still be used to qualify for Unsung Hero.

Comment: @Caleb Yes, I'll remove that part because it may lead to confusion. What I wanted to say is that if they had exactly 10 zero score answers at the moment they earned the badge, the condition is `>= 10`.

Comment: nah, this isn't right.

Comment: @Caleb i did not have any +1/-1 when i met the criteria of 10.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know a is more than 10 is equivalent to `a>10` and thus `a=10` will fail the check.

Comment: I also think so, but wanted to get the confirmation of that. Making it from 11 looks strange.