# The Unsung Hero and Tenacious badges should be reworded

Tags: feature-request, wording, zero-score-badges

The [Unsung Hero badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) has several serious problems with its description. (also note that the [Tenacious badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) is very similar and has all of the same issues)

The way it currently is worded:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

But this does not actually match when the badge is actually rewarded. As can be seen from [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103595/unsung-heroes-with-exactly-10-zero-score-accepted-answers) [written by A. Rodas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172191/158209), there are a handful of users who have the badge even though they have *exactly* 10 zero score accepted answers, i.e., not more than 10.

The badge behavior should match the description. That part of the description would be correct if it had the following format.

> Zero score accepted answers: (10 or more)|(at least 10)

And while we're at it, I think the last phrase should be reworded as well. The phrase "25% of total" literally implies *exactly* 25%, whereas the badge is rewarded when it is *at least* 25% of the total. It would be clearer if it was reworded to something of this format

> Zero score accepted answers: (10 or more)|(at least 10) and (25% or more)|(at least 25%) of total.

Finally, what does "of total" mean? Is it the total number of accepted answers you have, or is the total number answers you have? (answer: accepted answers) The badge would be more correct and less ambiguous if it was reworded thus

> Zero score accepted answers: (10 or more)|(at least 10) and (25% or more)|(at least 25%) of total number of accepted answers.

or perhaps even totally reworded, like this:

> at least 25% of all accepted answers, with a minimum of 10, have a score of zero.

And of course, if you have a better way to reword it, please suggest it.

Comment: The format `Zero score accepted answers: X or more and at least Y% of total accepted answers` seems very clear for me.

Comment: 2 more ambiguities:  1.  Are self-answers included in the zero-score-and-accepted count?  ...and even if you think the answer to that is obvious, there is still...  2.  Are self-answers included in the total number of accepted answers?  That is not clear at all.

Comment: That data query is meaningless. It's perfectly possible (and very likely for this particular badge) for a user to gain the badge and then fall back below the threshold. I wouldn't take those results as proof that it's "at least 10" versus "more than 10"... You need dev verification for that.

Answer (score 2):

At least ten accepted answers with a score of zero, and less than three times as many with other scores.

At least ten zero-scored accepted answers, making up at least a quarter of all accepted answers.

Ten or more zero-scored accepted answers, with other accepted answers numbering less than three times that.