# Fix ambiguities in the descriptions of the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges

Tags: feature-request, wording, zero-score-badges

The descriptions of the badges for zero-score accepted answers are written as:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than [x] and [y]% of total

As an example, the Unsung Hero badge's description is written as:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

The badge description as written has two ambiguities, which have resulted in [confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359546/users-should-have-the-unsung-hero-badge-but-they-have-not) from [multiple users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362981/why-havent-i-received-badge-unsung-hero-even-after-10-days):

- Many users misinterpret the text as "[x] or more", when it is in fact "more than [x]" (the same as "[x+1] or more"), as [confirmed by an employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359551/377214), and are left wondering why they didn't receive a badge on having [x] qualifying answers. My two prior links show that this has come up multiple times here on this meta, and possibly on other sites' metas as well, and the author of the accepted answer to the second post suggested that this wording be changed.
- It's unclear whether or not having exactly [y]% of total accepted answers be qualifying answers will meet the badge criteria. This doesn't merely stem from misinterpretation on users' parts: **there are multiple valid interpretations of the text in English**. "more than" can either be read as modifying the whole rest of the text (which is the interpretation used, as confirmed by staff in the link above), or as only modifying the number "[x]" and not the rest of the text. In the second interpretation, as the "[y]% of total" isn't being modified, it can implicitly mean "exactly [y]% of total" or "at least [y]% of total", neither of which is correct.

Can we please change the short description of these badges from saying "more than [x]" to "[x+1] or more" or "at least [x+1]", and explicitly indicate that a higher percentage is required? This will prevent users from being confused in these ways.

I suggest the following wording:

> Zero score accepted answers: at least [x] and more than [y]% of total

This suggested wording will fix both of the issues I pointed out: the English ambiguity in the percentage, and the common misinterpretation in the number of answers.

This is not a duplicate of the following posts:

- [Clarity in definitions of Tenacious and Unsung Hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/clarity-in-definitions-of-tenacious-and-unsung-hero) - that asks about the words next to the numbers (i.e. the phrases "zero-score accepted answers" and "of total"), not the numbers themselves
- [The Unsung Hero and Tenacious badges should be reworded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172195/377214) - that is based on a mistaken interpretation of the badge criteria, and incorrectly asks for the exact opposite as here (i.e. the author there believes that it's awarded at exactly on the quoted numbers and percentages, which is not the case as per the staff confirmation linked above).

Comment: Can someone please let me know of the reasons against implementing this, so I can edit this post to address them?

Comment: Didn't downvote but personally, I would highlight the second argument (e.g., place it first) because it sheds light on the part that's _actually_ confusing and ambiguous. Users reading "more than x" as "x or more" are just not paying attention. The downvotes are probably coming from users who only read your first argument and don't think the text should be changed based on that

Comment: @41686d6564 The impetus for this feature request came mainly from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362986/377214), which only suggested the first change; the second change is something I thought about later as I was writing this. I've since edited it to make clear there are two suggested changes.

Comment: What I like about the current descriptions is that they use nice round numbers. I wouldn't be opposed to a change to 'at least 5/10' but that would change the award criteria.

Comment: @Glorfindel The Populist badge description doesn't use nice round numbers. Also, using more accurate and less ambiguous wording is less important in my mind than having the description look aesthetically nice. Let's not emphasize form over function.

Comment: @Glorfindel Would you agree to a change that only fixes the second issue, if you think the first one isn't an issue?

Comment: Populist uses 10 and 2x (in the description, not the FAQ), those are nice numbers. I guess I could live with 'more than 10 and more than 25% of total'. And form *is* important; many badges have restrictions (e.g. no self-accepts, no community wiki posts) which belong in the FAQ, not the description, which needs to be concise and easily parseable. Using round numbers helps with the latter.